# on clicking the image doesn't load in chrome

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

My case: on clicking on a button the shade should appear and a loading image should be shown

```
<div id="shade" style="display:none;"></div>
<div id="modal" style="display:none;">
</div>




 function showModal(){
            $('#shade').show();
            $('#modal').show();
                $('#modal').html("<div class='img' style='z-index: 99999; top:65px; display: block;'></div>"); //dint do this directly in html because it isn't working on IE
            $('.img').show();
        }
```

using the above code, it works on all browsers except for chrome. can someone please help..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

http://jsfiddle.net/DKgQM/

You need to specify the width and height of .img

Comment: maybe it's overridden? Can You see the image in the jsfiddle example while testing in chrome?

Comment: yaa i can see it in jsfiddle.. but i wont work in my project... :(